# JS PDF Blob empty page

Tags: javascript, c#, pdf, blob

I'm using external Rest API to get spedition label for package. In response I have:

```
%PDF-1.4\n%����\n6 0 obj\n<</ColorSpace[/Indexed/DeviceRGB 255(\0\0\0 [...]
```

Now I need to display PDF in browser

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('POST', '/Order/CreateShipmentInpost', true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    xhr.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
    xhr.onload = function (e) {
        if (this.status == 200) {
            var blob = new Blob([this.response], { type: "application/pdf" });
            var link = document.createElement('a');
            link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            link.download = "Report.pdf";
            link.click();
        }
    };
    xhr.send($.param(data));
```

In generated PDF file is only blank page. I don't know why content is not showing.

[image: PDF empty page]

I'm using `responseType = 'arraybuffer'`. Controller returns:

```
 return File(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data, MediaTypeNames.Application.Pdf);
```

I also tried to return json or string, but PDF was always empty.

Comment: Hey ! Did you find a solution since then ?

Comment: Not exactly. As I remember I made workaround with php script.